# get_post_meta not working with variable

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

I want to return an image from a custom post and i have :

```
$pidd=$row1['id_promotora'];


$imageid=get_post_meta( $pidd,  '_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_5_fieldID_2_numInSet_0', $single = true ); 
echo "imagemid:".$imageid."<br><br>";
echo wp_get_attachment_image($imageid, 'fullmark');
```

the output of $pidd is my post id 3245, if i use

```
$imageid=get_post_meta( 3245,  '_simple_fields_fieldGroupID_5_fieldID_2_numInSet_0', $single = true );
```

it works fine..but when i user the variable $pidd it dosent... strange thing... any clue ?

Comment: Show expecting, and actual results.

Comment: i want to display an image ..the 3245 is the id of that image ...but since its a loop im using a variable ...it dosent works ...but if i use the id instead of the variable it works... ( the output os that variable is the same 3245! )

Comment: `var_dump($pidd)` and see what you're really dealing with. don't echo, don't print_r, use var_dump. it'll tell you how long the string is - e.g. if there's any hidden/unprintable chars, you'll just echo out `3245`, but get something like `string(10) '3245'` - gee - 4 visible chars, but the strings 10 chars long.

Comment: i get string(6) " 3245 " but.. should it be string(4) " 3245 "?

Comment: may be white spaces ?

Comment: thats it ..tks alot to everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was the white spaces in my sting...with var_dump i was able to debug the problem and use :

```
$pidd1 = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $row1['id_promotora']);
```

to fix it ..tks